# Incomplete PATH variable

Tags: c#, .net, macos, path, mono

I'm trying to retrieve the value of the `PATH` variable in Mono on OSX. However, I'm not getting the same result from the terminal.

In C# (incomplete):

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH")
```

> /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

In terminal (expected):

```
echo $PATH
```

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:.:~/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/php5/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands

I tried using every available `EnvironmentVariableTarget` as a second parameter for `GetEnvironmentVariable` but none return the full path.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Your application is using a different environment than your terminal.

Comment: Yeah, that's basically your problem. When the terminal launches it executes some files that prepare the environment. In Linux systems there's commonly a 'profile' file and also '.bashrc' in the user folder, those files normally modify and augment the system environment variables.

Comment: I'm mostly interested in getting the Mono commands path; any way I could load the same profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When starting a new Terminal window, the shell automatically executes `/etc/profile` and `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal` (or `/etc/bashrc` when not using Terminal).

Part of `/etc/profile` is to run `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`, which builds a path command adding additional elements to your path, in addition to the "default" elements that you also see when using `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Path")`.

For a general solution to getting the exact path the shell uses, you can use the following code:

```
var info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.FileName = "/bin/bash";
info.Arguments = "-l -c \"echo $PATH\""; // -l = 'login shell' so we execute /etc/profile
info.UseShellExecute = false;
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
info.RedirectStandardError = true;
var p = Process.Start(info);
p.WaitForExit();

string path = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd().Trim();  // Drop the trailing \n from our echo output
```

However, if you simply want the path that is specific to mono, you can just read the contents of the file `/etc/paths.d/mono-commands`. That is where the shell, via `path_helper`, gets the mono path that is added to the Path variable.